# How do I get Sharepoint to retrieve data from another database?

Tags: sharepoint, database

I would like Sharepoint to present the content of a view from another server. There is no need to modify the data, but sorting would be nice.

Can I accomplish this without (too much) coding?

Comment: What do you mean by "other server"? Is it another SharePoint or something else?

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options:

1. Run custom code in SharePoint that connects to the database and queries the information. This could be a custom webpart or a new page that you put in the _layouts folder.
2. Instead of connecting to the database directly, you could publish the data using a web service or an RSS feed. That way, you don't have to worry about a DB connection. You could connect to this using a Content Editor webpart and custom JavaScript.

Those are just two options--there are others. Really, it depends a lot on what you need to do. For example, should any SharePoint user be able to see the data pulled from the database? How are you going to handle security? Are there dozens of rows you're pulling from the database or millions?

Anything you do will require some amount of coding.

Comment: +1. Totally spaced on the web service idea.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, you could use reporting services on your SharePoint box to present the data, if you're running SRS. Alternately, you could dig into the business data catalog (BDC):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms563661.aspx

The latter assumes you're running MOSS 2007.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you just want to fetch data from another database, may be of SqlServer. If this is the case you can simply use SPD to accomplish your task.

Open SPD, Create a new DataSource, and connect to your desired database, and table/view. then go to the page where you want to display the data inside SPD. Edit page in normal mode, place cursor at the place where you want to display the data and goto Insert > Data View > (and select your desired source from DataBase connections)

It should be done.